# Should Fama-French coefficients be calculated with daily or monthly returns?

Tags: regression, high-frequency, fama-french, statistical-significance

I noticed when I regress the return of a portfolio on the Fama French 3 factor model that the value and the statistical significance of the coefficients vary when I use daily versus monthly portfolio returns. I would like to know what is the best frequency to estimate these coefficients?

For my purpose I do need to use higher frequency data (daily)

Answer (score 1):

In this context, I refer to the book on [Empirical Asset Pricing](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Empirical+Asset+Pricing%3A+The+Cross+Section+of+Stock+Returns-p-9781118095041) by Bali, Engle and Murray (2016). They state on page 124 that

> A minimum number of data points are usually required to ensure the
> quality of the values estimated by the regression. In the case of
> daily data over a one-year period, a reasonable requirement may be
> that the regression be fit using at least 200 data points. While using
> one year’s worth of daily data to calculate beta is common, other
> estimation period lengths and data frequencies are also used. Another
> common approach is to use monthly excess return data from the past
> five years.

Its basically a regression and usual regression thumb rules are applicable.